# How to rename files(and move them) in PowerShell 5.1?

Tags: powershell, rename, powershell-5.1

I am new to PowerShell and I am stuck at something really simple. I have Googled a lot and got this far but can't seem to resolve this. I am trying to do a simple file transfer from one server to the other.
The purpose of the script is to check if the file in the source folder exists in the destination folder, if it does, prepend `"Copy_"` in the name of the file and move all the contents of the folder including the renamed files in the destination folder.

`Move-Item` works but it moves all the content before renaming them. Therefore, there are no issues with the paths or the connection.

`Write-Output $file` returns `True` which is correct, there are duplicate files in the destination folder.
The issues are:

1. Renaming of files is not working. It just adds a new file called "Copy_" in the source folder. All the files except this new "Copy_" file are moved.
2. I get this error for each file in the source folder `Get-ChildItem : Could not find item \\server9\VantageAttachments_ProblemsFolder\Vantage_test\NameOfTheFile.txt.` Which is triggered by line  `Get-ChildItem -Force $sourcePath | ForEach-Object`

> ```
> $sourcePath = "\\server9\VantageAttachments_ProblemsFolder\Vantage_test\*.*"
> $DestinationPath = "\\server2\MfgLib\RevisedPrograms\MC-A\Copied_From_Mazak"
>
> Get-ChildItem -Force $sourcePath | ForEach-Object {
>     # Check if the file in the Source folder is in Destination folder
>     $fileName = $_.Name
>     $file = Test-Path -Path $DestinationPath\$fileName
>     Write-Output $file
>     if($file){
>         "\\server9\VantageAttachments_ProblemsFolder\Vantage_test\$fileName" | Rename-Item -NewName {"Copy_"+$_.Name};
>         
>     }
>     Move-Item -Path $sourcePath  -Destination $DestinationPath -Force
>
> }
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$sourcePath = "\\server9\VantageAttachments_ProblemsFolder\Vantage_test\*.*"
$DestinationPath = "\\server2\MfgLib\RevisedPrograms\MC-A\Copied_From_Mazak"

Get-ChildItem -Force $sourcePath | ForEach-Object {
    # Check if the file in the Source folder is in Destination folder
        $fileName = $_.Name
        $file = Test-Path -Path $DestinationPath\$fileName
        Write-Output $file
            if($file){
                 "\\server9\VantageAttachments_ProblemsFolder\Vantage_test\$fileName" | Rename-Item -NewName ("Copy_"+$_.Name);
            }
           
}
Move-Item -Path $sourcePath  -Destination $DestinationPath -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

`Copy_` is not being moved because in `$source` you specified that a file has to have an extension `*.*`.
Try using parentheses instead of curly brackets in Rename-Item. I think that it is a scoping error, and that because of that `$_.Name` is empty.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It kind of works. The filename is changed to `Copy_Filename` but it does it only for the first file in the folder. I need this process repeated until there are no duplicates left.